# How to reset a VM password in Azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/reset-rdp
says for resetting a password via the Azure Portal method:

> Select your Windows VM and then select Reset password under Support + Troubleshooting.

But I cannot see in the sidebar or menu "Support + Troubleshooting"

[image: Azure sidebar screenshot]

The nearest possible option I can see is "Diagnose and solve problems" but that doesn't contain any "Reset Password" option, so I cannot work out how to reset a VM password in Azure? I am assuming the docu is out of date, please does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

The `Support + troubleshooting` is a category in on the VM blade.
[image: Reset password screen]

You can also use the `Search` box on the top of the page ([Ctrl]+[/]) to search for specific pages.

Comment: Thankyou Jan_V - I must be on the wrong page. The sidebar I see is different (now screenshot linked from original query)

Comment: How is the menu in your screenshot reached? The sidebar I see is different (screenshot now added as link from original query)

Comment: Isn't there a scrollbar? You should be able to scroll down. Otherwise, use the Search editbox on the top (visible in your screenshot) and type `Reset password`.

Comment: Thankyou, but didnt find and recreated the VM